# use ajax to autocomplete

Tags: php, ajax

Maybe u can help with with some ajax issue.

I have AUTO COMPLETE code - I type the city name and the code auto-completes it for me and also get the city ID and supposed to put in in a hidden input field (name='cityID')...but it doesn't do that.

Can you tell me why?

html code:

```
<p><label>city: </label><input type='text' name='cityName' value='$cityName'  id='keyword_city' autocomplete='off' />
    <span id='ajax_response_city' class='ajax_response' style='display:none;' ></span>
    <input type='hidden' name='cityID' value='$cityID' id='keyword_cityID'>
</p>
```

server side (only the output):

```
echo '<li><a href=\'javascript:void(0);\' data-id="'.$row['cityID'].'">'.$final.'</a></li>';
```

script:

```
$("#ajax_response_city").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find("li a").mouseover(function () {
          $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
    $(this).find("li a").mouseout(function () {
          $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(this).find("li a").click(function () {
          $("#keyword_city").val($(this).text());
          $("#keyword_cityID").val($(this).data().id);
          $("#ajax_response_city").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

The full JS you can find here:

```
http://www.dogger.co.il/js/ajax/autoComplate_city.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a div instead of a span tag for ajax_response_city.
The html gets messed up and your selections won't work anymore.

I put together an example: http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/86T4f/

```
<div id='ajax_response_city' class='ajax_response'></div>
```

I would also start using proper html (like put li elements in ul or ol) to avoid issues like that.

Comment: thanks, but the issue is with the cityID field: <input type='hidden' name='cityID' value='$cityID' id='keyword_cityID'>

Comment: Look at the example I made. It gets updated just like you wanted it to.

Comment: I looked at your example, but I'm not see where input "cityID" get the "data-id" value from: <a href='javascript:void(0);' data-id="someID">test</a>

Comment: Again, I'm pretty sure it does --> Before clicking test : <input type="hidden" name="cityID" value="$cityID" id="keyword_cityID"> and after clicking test : <input type="hidden" name="cityID" value="someID" id="keyword_cityID"> notice the value changed to someID which was the data-id value of your a tag

Comment: yes, you are right/ and I'm using the same code. I have no idea why it isn't working for me...:/