# Ajax autocomplete for cities

Tags: php, ajax

I have AUTO COMPLETE code - I type the city name and the code auto-completes it for me and also get the city ID and supposed to put in in a hidden input field (name='cityID')...but it doesn't do that.

Can you tell me why?

html code:

```
<p><label>city: </label><input type='text' name='cityName' value='$cityName'  id='keyword_city' autocomplete='off' />
    <span id='ajax_response_city' class='ajax_response' style='display:none;' ></span>
    <input type='hidden' name='cityID' value='$cityID' id='keyword_cityID'>
</p>
```

server side (only the output):

```
echo '<li><a href=\'javascript:void(0);\' data-id="'.$row['cityID'].'">'.$cityName.'</a></li>';
```

script:

```
$("#ajax_response_city").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find("li a").mouseover(function () {
          $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
    $(this).find("li a").mouseout(function () {
          $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(this).find("li a").click(function () {
          $("#keyword_city").val($(this).text());
          $("#keyword_cityID").val($(this).data().id);
          $("#ajax_response_city").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

The full JS you can be found here:

```
http://www.dogger.co.il/js/ajax/autoComplate_city.js
```

the issue is with:

```
<input type='hidden' name='cityID' value='$cityID' id='keyword_cityID'>
```

($cityID doesn't get the value...)

Comment: didn't you already ask this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638721/use-ajax-to-autocomplete

Comment: `$(this).data().id` Why in the world would you think there is such a thing?  `$(this).data()` is HTML, right?  So what is `.id` of HTML?  It doesn't exist....or am I wrong?

Comment: nope that part is correct. http://api.jquery.com/data/